# CreateJS get the total frame number of a spritesheet

Tags: createjs

I am building a spritesheetbuilder class when I can pass in spritesheets that may have a different number of total frames and I would like to know is there a way to dynamically find out how many frames there are in a spritesheet and then loop through them all without having to setup the animations frame by frame? The loop parameter is a boolean value already working.

```
 //SpriteSheetAnimator(bmp, w, h, loop)
 this.monitor = new SpriteSheetAnimator(loader.getResult('img'), 204, 189, true);

 //inside the SpriteSheetAnimator object
  this._ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
                    animations:{
                        play:{
                            frames: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
                            speed: 0.4
                        },
                    images:[this.bmp],
                    frames: {
                        width:this.width,
                        height:this.height,
                        regX:this.width*0.5,
                        regY:this.height*0.5
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play all of the frames in a `Sprite`, just play it from `0`: `mySprite.gotoAndPlay(0)`

To get the number of frames, use `mySpriteSheet.getNumFrames()`.

http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheet.html